# Can't install mongoose due to EPERM error

Tags: node.js, npm, mongoose, npm-install

I got an EPERM error when i tried to install mongoose. I've tried running the command as an administrator and it still didn't work

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\HP PAVILION 15\Desktop\proshop\node_modules\.sift.DELETE\MIT-LICENSE.txt
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\HP PAVILION 15\Desktop\proshop\node_modules\.sift.DELETE\MIT-LICENSE.txt'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\HP PAVILION 15\Desktop\proshop\node_modules\.sift.DELETE\MIT-LICENSE.txt'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\HP PAVILION 15\Desktop\proshop\node_modules\.sift.DELETE\MIT-LICENSE.txt'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\HP PAVILION 15\\Desktop\\proshop\\node_modules\\.sift.DELETE\\MIT-LICENSE.txt'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\HP PAVILION 15\\Desktop\\proshop\\node_modules\\.sift.DELETE\\MIT-LICENSE.txt',
npm ERR!   parent: 'proshop'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HPPAVI~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-17T07_37_57_494Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you tried `npm install mongoose --save`?

Comment: Try to run cmd or powershell with admin permission. I solved EPERM error with this way.

Comment: I tried this "npm install mongoose --save" and running it as administrator. They both gave me the EPERM error